# kismet on BCM43227

Tags: wireless

I am trying to monitor wireless on Broadcom BCM43227,
I used sudo airmon-ng to run the monitoring, i get command not found.
I installed kismet, when i run, i get this

```
uttam@UT:~$ sudo kismet
Launching kismet_server: //usr/bin/kismet_server
Suid priv-dropping disabled.  This may not be secure.
No specific sources given to be enabled, all will be enabled.
Non-RFMon VAPs will be destroyed on multi-vap interfaces (ie, madwifi-ng)
Enabling channel hopping.
Enabling channel splitting.
NOTICE: Disabling channel hopping, no enabled sources are able to change channel.
Source 0 (addme): Opening none source interface none...
FATAL: Please configure at least one packet source.  Kismet will not function if no packet sources are defined in kismet.conf or on the command line.  Please read the README for more information about configuring Kismet.
Kismet exiting.
Done.
uttam@UT:~$
```

I did check a blog about kismet on Broadcom that says about some binary drivers not allowing to do it...

I used iwconfig and it says no extension : what is that

well I need to give a hand on air monitoring............ help, how to do it

Answer (score 1):

- http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1655021

the above links help in finding, that my card isn't support i.e. BCM43227

Answer (score 0):

The correct driver for your wireless device is the Broadcom proprietary driver provided by bcmwl-kernel-source. As for Kismet, their documentation clearly says:

```
  Broadcom has released a binary version of their drivers called WL.
  These drivers are incapable of monitor mode, and cannot be used with
  Kismet.  Kismet will attempt to autodetect them and report this to the 
  user.  Users of Broadcom cards should use the b43 or b43xx in-kernel
  drivers.
```

Your device, this, I believe, is not claimed by b43 and ssb:

```
 Broadcom Corporation BCM43227 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4358]
```

I don't believe there is any method or driver to get monitoring with this device.